# Custom TableLayout row android

Tags: android, custom-controls, row, tablelayout

[image]

I need to implement this one as a table row - I have such fields as ID (39004), Title(I finally reached a milestone), Status(Checking) and Price($456). How can I do it? Or does it better to implement this in some another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with the RelativeLayout like this:

item.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <!-- ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/altOrderId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ID"
            android:gravity="center|center"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Title Of Song -->

    <!-- Artist Name -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/altOrderTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Just gona stand there and ..."
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <!-- Rightend Duration -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/altOrderStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/altOrderTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="#838B8B"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Rightend Arrow -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/altOrderPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Rihanna Love the way lie"
        android:textColor="#458B74"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my list.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/altOrderslist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layoutLabel"

        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
         />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this is not a custom table layout.